# How do I customise the indents of successively lower levels of hierarchy in Excel 2013 Pivot Table report?

Tags: excel, pivot, indentation, hierarchy, presentation

Does anyone know of a way to customise indentation of hierarchical levels within Excel Pivot Table displays? My pivot contains 5 levels of hierarchy and I'd prefer to incrementally indent each successively-lower level of the hierarchy by, say 5 characters.

Comment: Brit: you may want to show an example and show the code that you have tried.  This is a good site for getting hep, but not for free coding.